# Простое условие JS работает через ZH

Tags: javascript, html

Возникла странная проблема, простой if отрабатывается всегда. Мне нужно, чтобы если inputPoints.value становился больше inputPoints.max, то всегда получал его (inputPoints.max) значение. Однако почему-то вот это условие выполняется всегда.

```
    if (inputPoints.value > inputPoints.max)
    {
        inputPoints.value = inputPoints.max;
    }
```

вот нужный input и вся функция целиком:

```
<input id="a" type="number" min="1" max="10" onchange="valid()">

<script>
    function valid()
    {
        let inputPoints = document.getElementById("a");

        if (inputPoints.value < inputPoints.min)
        {
            inputPoints.value = inputPoints.min;
        }

        if (inputPoints.value > inputPoints.max)
        {
            inputPoints.value = inputPoints.max;
        }

        if (inputPoints.value % 1 != 0)
        {
            inputPoints.value = "";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Результат сейчас: в любой ситуации, когда inputPoints.value > 1, принимается значение 10, хотя должно только при inputPoints.value > 10.

Comment: let min = parseInt(inputPoints.getAttribute("min"));
let max = parseInt(inputPoints.getAttribute("max"));
let value = parseInt(inputPoints.value);

//а уже дальше сравнивайте и присваивайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё делло в том что вы сравниваете не числа, а строки. А при [сравнении строк](https://learn.javascript.ru/comparison#sravnenie-raznyh-tipov) сравнивается по символьно и получается сравнение `'2'` и `'10'`, а `'2'` больше чем `'1'`. Потому вам надо прежде преобразовать строчные значения в числовые:

```js
const inputPoints = document.getElementById("a");
const inputPointsMax = +inputPoints.max;
const inputPointsMin = +inputPoints.min;

console.log(typeof inputPoints.value, typeof inputPoints.max);

function valid() {
  const currentValue = +inputPoints.value;

  if (currentValue < inputPointsMin) {
    inputPoints.value = inputPointsMin;
  }

  if (currentValue > inputPointsMax) {
    inputPoints.value = inputPointsMax;
  }

  if (currentValue % 1 != 0) {
    inputPoints.value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="a" type="number" min="1" max="10" value="4" onchange="valid()">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло